# Identifiers in the C language where are they stored

Tags: c, memory, stack, identifier

Just interested. I'm revising my long forgotten rusty knowledge  of C and am wondering  in C where are the identifiers for declared variables stored?

For example if I declare the following char value1 in main.

```
int main(){
char value1 = 'A';
  return 0;
}
```

I know that the char will be stored at in a the stack in the Stack Frame for main. Lets say if we did an address off on on value1 like this &value1.  We would get something like 0xF37012 ( a hypothetical number). This would be where the value is located, but what about the identifier? and how is this associated with 0xF37012?   Is it in the stack frane for main someplace? Or do all all identifiers get stored on some global table, or list?

Comment: The names like `value1` are not needed (because it is a local variable, not an externally visible name), but will be kept in the debugging information if the code is compiled with debugging enabled.  External names (such as `main()`) are preserved at least until the program is linked because the linker needs to resolve them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have compiled specifically for debugging, the identifiers are *NOT* stored. If you did set the debuggability option when you compiled, there will be symbol tables associated with functions/stack-frames/static storage which provide those mappings.

Comment: Ahaa this makes complete sense. From this I infer all the variables are in fact is just memory locations, named for our convenience. So when the computer is pushing values around, it's not referencing say value1, but 0xF37012, and hypothetically the resultant machine code would replace all references of the identifier value1 with 0xF37012. Yep brilliant thanks. Clean and clear.

Comment: @AndrewS that is correct enough for a basic understanding, but note that there might be more than one "value1" if the function is recursive. 0xF37012 would be used for global variables, but for locals it's more like (start_of_local_variables + 0x0056) and start_of_local_variables can change for each function call.

Comment: And, as @hurricane1026 pointed out below, the compiler may reuse a single address (or address range) for multiple identifiers, if their scopes don't overlap. For that matter, the compiler may optimize the memory references away entirely if the values can be kept in registers long enough to serve their purpose before the registers are needed for other things.

Comment: @Imbibis thanks for making that clear. Makes sense again as each recursive call would have it's own stack frame thus own local copy of value1.

Answer (score 0):

some identifier will be optimized while compiling, unless generated debug informations.